# Programmatically create Virtual Directory in Root of website

Tags: .net, servermanager

How can I programmatically (vb.net or C#) create a Virtual Directory in the Root of website in IIS7?

[Using this link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosag/archive/2006/04/17/microsoftwebadministration.aspx), it only shows you how to make one inside an application but I need it at the ROOT level of the website.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This worked on my machine (notice the indexes in second line):

```
ServerManager iisManager = new ServerManager();
Application app = iisManager.Sites[0].Applications[0];
app.VirtualDirectories.Add("/VDir", "d:\\MyVDir");
iisManager.Update();
```

Comment: so iisManager.Sites[0].Applications[0] is the root website and not an application in the root of the website?

Comment: You cannot add a virtual directory to the website itself, but to its application (notice the picture in the link that you provided). I guess `Sites[0].Applications[0]` returns the default application for the root website.